# My Today extension content is empty when I run on my App Scheme

Tags: ios8, ios8-today-widget

This is my **widget** scheme. When I run the app, everything is ok, widget is working...

[image]

[image]

... but why when I change the scheme to my **App Scheme** then there is no content?

[image]
[image]

There is a message on console:
`NewOrders[7930:96020] Failed to inherit CoreMedia permissions from 7899: (null)`

**UPDATE:**
**It is not working only on iPhone 6 and 6 Plus**

Comment: You'll need to give us some more details. This could be caused by 100 different things.

Comment: @bgilham - I updated a question with a message on console

Comment: I have the same problem, how did You solve it?